# How to crosstab with a composite "row name"

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have following table with `id(intger), project (varchar), month (varchar), hours (integer)`

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id,project,month,hours)
    AS VALUES
    ( 1 , 'A', 'aug', 1 ),
    ( 1 , 'A', 'sep', 3 ),
    ( 1 , 'B', 'aug', 2 ),
    ( 1 , 'B', 'sep', 5 ),
    ( 2 , 'A', 'aug', 2 ),
    ( 2 , 'A', 'sep', 4 );
```

I wanted below table

```
|id | project | aug | sep |
|1  | A       | 1   | 3   |
|1  | B       | 2   | 5   |
|2  | A       | 2   | 4   |
```

I read this can be possible with an array but it seems like documentation is confusing. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did my answer satisfy the question? https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crosstab` doesn't permit composite keys. it requires rows provide a unique identifier for which to pivot them on. This means in your case `(id,project)` has to be serialized. You can do this with `jsonb`, or array or the like. Here I'm just using a `text[]`.

```
SELECT id, project, aug, sep
FROM crosstab(
  $$
    SELECT ARRAY[id,project]::text[], id, project, month, hours
    FROM foo
    ORDER BY 1
  $$,
  $$
    SELECT DISTINCT month FROM foo ORDER BY 1
  $$
) AS c(rn text[], id int,project text,aug int,sep int);

 id | project | aug | sep 
----+---------+-----+-----
  1 | A       |   1 |   3
  1 | B       |   2 |   5
  2 | A       |   2 |   4
(3 rows)
```

A couple of notes,

- you should probably be storing `month` as a `date.`
- you may also want to look at the [MADlib pivot](http://madlib.apache.org/docs/latest/group__grp__pivot.html) which does permit composite keys.

There are lots of other ways you can solve this problem too without using crosstab,

```
SELECT id, project, jsonb_object_agg( month, hours ) AS month_hours
FROM foo
GROUP BY id, project
ORDER BY 1,2;
 id | project |     month_hours      
----+---------+----------------------
  1 | A       | {"aug": 1, "sep": 3}
  1 | B       | {"aug": 2, "sep": 5}
  2 | A       | {"aug": 2, "sep": 4}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I think this assumes that `select distinct month...` will output the months in the natural order, which it won't generally. Because of that, IHMO crosstab() is not very helpful in this case, whereas a 12-step `CASE WHEN month=... THEN sum()... as "month-name"` with just a GROUP BY would get the job done.

Comment: @DanielVérité it assumes and (now) enforces alphabetical order If he needs natural he should be using `date`.